# Is checking for double dots enough to prevent paths from escaping jail?

Tags: security, http, sanitization

I'm writing a service that sends over the network the contents of requested files.  However, I'll only answer requests for files that descend from a fixed `parent` directory.

The first potential security problem that comes to mind is that an evil user may request paths with `..` embedded.  Another potential problem are symlinks, though these should not be an issue since I control the local filesystem and there won't be any simlinks under `parent`.

My question is therefore whether it is enough to check for the existence of `..` among the path components.  Or is there some other security vulnerability I have forgotten?

Comment: As you don't consider the normalization approach suggested in my answer, please give more specifics. What OS? What API do you use to get the files? An all-encompassing answer is nearly impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to go about it would be to

- normalize/canonicalize the requested path
- check if the (normalized) parent directory is a prefix of the requested path

That way you can be absolutely sure. This requires a working normalizer. Use the one provided by your programming environment, like [path.normalize()](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_p), [readlink -f](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink), etc.

If there is none, security-wise it's no problem to write it yourself. You normalize what you know ('..' goes one up - or you ignore it, making it illegal), and what is left as-is will be rejected by the check above. It should be obvious, but of course you must only use the normalized path later on for accessing the file, not the one provided by the user.

One thing you should make sure is that the normalized parent directory ends with a trailing slash (or backslash, if on Windows), otherwise users could get access to folders on the same level as parentDir that start with the same characters as parentDir.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the canonicalisation approach.  However, it seems like a brute force solution if the answer to my initial question would be a resolute "yes".  Therefore, my initial question stands...

Comment: It's a solution that works 100%. It's hard to give assurances for your approach. You overlook one thing, and there's your security hole. So in practice, I'd probably prefer normalization to be on the safe side. Otoh as a general question I find it interesting, too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget double slash `example//path`. Some systems treat these as `/path`.

Comment: Do you have an example? I've always seen it being treated as a single slash, on Unix-like systems.